# such as + auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar

> Now if this party is **such as may** please one, we hope you'll receive
>   them, for here we must leave the, wishing you all the good things of
>   the season.

It's from the 19th-century children's poem called King Luckieboy's Party by Walter Crane.
For me, it looks grammatically strange to put 'may' after 'such as'. 
How come it is possible and how can I interpret this part?

I leave the internet source of this poem here.
https://ufdc.ufl.edu/UF00086956/00001/28x

Comment: The meaning should be "if this party is one of those that one might find pleasant/displays features that may please one".

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid but somewhat old usage. It is used in old prose as well as in modern-day legalese. Especially the following phrase which is somewhat common in legal documents

> Such as may be considered expedient/necessary

In this case, "such as" means "of the type/kind that"

So the author means

> If the party is of the kind that will please one, we hope you'll
>   receive them